# nginx rewrite regex matching first group instead of all

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm working on an nginx rewrite rule to redirect:

/collections/collection-name/products/product-handle-with-dashes

to:

/products/product-handle-with-dashes

I've got it almost working, the only issue I have right now if my rule to match the product handle is only returning the first string before the first hyphen.

My rule:
`rewrite ^(/collections/.*)/products/(\w+)\.?.*$ /products/$2 permanent;`

With this rule if I hit the following path: /collections/collection-name/products/some-product-handle it will redirect me to /products/some

what am I missing on my regex to allow it my second variable to capture the entire handle with dashes.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` metacharacter of the PCRE/PCRE2 regex patterns include characters from ranges `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` **and** underscore. It does not include a hyphen. You probably want `[-\w]` instead. The whole rewrite rule can be the

```
rewrite ^/collections/[^/]+(/products/[-\w]+)(\.\w+)?$ $1 permanent;
```